# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I can't get access to my WP (version3.4.2) admin. It says as mentioned above

> Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/rtthemes16/rt-framework/classes/admin.php on line 540.

The line 540 is :

```
function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST){

    if(is_array($_POST)){

        $start_unset_count = 0;

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if(stristr($key, '_sidebar_name') == TRUE && $value=="") {                  
                unset($_POST[$key]);
                $start_unset_count = 1;
            }

            if($start_unset_count>0){
                unset($_POST[$key]);
                $start_unset_count++;
            }

            if($start_unset_count==6){
                $start_unset_count = 0;
            }               
        }
    }


    $newPost == $newPost ? $newPost : $_POST;       
    return $_POST;
}
```

Any insights? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

Since PHP 5.4, you cannot use a superglobal as the parameter to a function

$_POST is globally accessible. So you don't have to pass to your function.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php#112184

This is how your function should look like

```
function rt_check_sidebar_array(){

    if(is_array($_POST)){

        $start_unset_count = 0;

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if(stristr($key, '_sidebar_name') == TRUE && $value=="") {                  
                unset($_POST[$key]);
                $start_unset_count = 1;
            }

            if($start_unset_count>0){
                unset($_POST[$key]);
                $start_unset_count++;
            }

            if($start_unset_count==6){
                $start_unset_count = 0;
            }               
        }
    }


    $newPost == $newPost ? $newPost : $_POST;       
    return $_POST;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise (bc the link suggests i rename the variable $)

Comment: if you rename your function param name then you can access $_POST data via that param name, the best thing would be to have no param at all in `function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST){` and should be as `function rt_check_sidebar_array(){` since you can access $_POST inside the function directly for any operation and this is true for any super globals like $_FILES, $_GET etc.

Comment: still the same line; 540

Comment: Check sidebar array 
 # 
 function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST){
   
  if(is_array($_POST)){
   
   $start_unset_count = 0;
   
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(stristr($key, '_sidebar_name') == TRUE && $value=="") {     
     unset($_POST[$key]);
     $start_unset_count = 1;
    }
    
    if($start_unset_count>0){
     unset($_POST[$key]);
     $start_unset_count++;
    }

    if($start_unset_count==6){
     $start_unset_count = 0;
    }    
   }
  }
  
  
  $newPost == $newPost ? $newPost : $_POST;  
  return $_POST;
 }

Comment: no u have not removed the $_POST in function param `function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST)` it should be just `function rt_check_sidebar_array()` and when u call this function just call it without any param.

Comment: theres the new one                                                             #
 # Check sidebar array 
 # 
 function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST){
   
  if(is_array()){
   
   $start_unset_count = 0;
   
   foreach( as $key => $value){
    if(stristr($key, '_sidebar_name') == TRUE && $value=="") {     
     unset([$key]);
     $start_unset_count = 1;
    }
    
    if($start_unset_count>0){
     unset([$key]);
     $start_unset_count++;
    }

    if($start_unset_count==6){
     $start_unset_count = 0;
    }    
   }
  }
  
  
  $newPost == $newPost ? $newPost : ;  
  return ;
 }

Comment: in the new one also u have `function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST)`.. please remove $_POST from the function parameter

Comment: Check sidebar array 
 # 
 function rt_check_sidebar_array(){
   
  if(is_array()){
   
   $start_unset_count = 0;
   
   foreach( as $key => $value){
    if(stristr($key, '_sidebar_name') == TRUE && $value=="") {     
     unset([$key]);
     $start_unset_count = 1;
    }
    
    if($start_unset_count>0){
     unset([$key]);
     $start_unset_count++;
    }

    if($start_unset_count==6){
     $start_unset_count = 0;
    }    
   }
  }
  
  
  $newPost == $newPost ? $newPost : ;  
  return ;
 }
  

 #

Comment: u are doing wrong again check my updated answer and I would suggest to learn more on PHP functions and arguments.

Comment: if u could send me the sentence i should use that would b very much appreciated.. im trying to fix things, every one is not as pro as u ..thanks

Comment: sentence ?? did not get what u mean.

Answer (score 7):

@user3450716, the only thing you need to do, as Abhik Chakraborty said, is to delete the `$_POST` from your function `rt_check_sidebar` parameters and leave the function with no parameters, like this:

your line 540:

```
function rt_check_sidebar_array($_POST){
```

change it to:

```
function rt_check_sidebar_array(){
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in fixing the install of MyITCRM.

Answer (score 3):

@user3450716.
You can't change superglobal variables too, so you can't use `unset($_POST[$key])`

```
function rt_check_sidebar_array(){
    $post = $_POST;
    if(is_array($post)){

        $start_unset_count = 0;

        foreach( $post as $key => $value ){
            if( stristr( $key, '_sidebar_name' ) == TRUE && $value == "" ) {                  
                unset( $post[ $key ] );
                $start_unset_count = 1;
            }

            if( $start_unset_count > 0 ){
                unset( $post[ $key ] );
                $start_unset_count++;
            }

            if( $start_unset_count == 6 ){
                $start_unset_count = 0;
            }               
        }
    }

    // idk why you wrote this,
    // because $newPost variable isn't used in the code above and below
    $newPost == $newPost ? $newPost : $post;

    return $post;
}
```