# Need help solving Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST

Tags: php, post

Below is the code. I tried what was suggested in a related post - removing $_post and also modifying it to $_MY_POST. Both result in several other errors across multiple files, etc. Can someone help? I am not a developer so I apologize for my ignorance in advance.

```
function clean_data($_POST){
         foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
            $POST[$k] = htmlentities(strip_tags(stripslashes($v)));
            $POST[$k] = addslashes($POST[$k]);
         }
return $POST;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable \_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583386/fatal-error-cannot-re-assign-auto-global-variable-post)

Answer (score 0):

You can't reassign a global variable like `$_POST`.
This code works:

```
function clean_data($data){
         foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            $_POST[$k] = htmlentities(strip_tags(stripslashes($v)));
            $_POST[$k] = addslashes($_POST[$k]);
         }
return $_POST;
}
```